# Comparar valor de 3 o más elementos a la vez en JAVA

Tags: java

¿Es posible comparar de alguna forma el valor de 3 o más elementos a la vez?

Algo tipo esto:

```
if (a == b == 3) {
  //código
}
```

Comment: No cuesta nada hacer la prueba ...

Answer (score 9):

Si me ciño a responder tu pregunta, dado que empiezas con *¿Es posible...* ***si, es posible***.

Es *correcto*??
Ya lo dudo, este tipo de expresiones da más lugar a equivocaciones y errores que la sintaxis *normal*. Por ejemplo, el código que has puesto tu en la pregunta **no funcionaría** puesto que en java las operaciones se evalúan de *izquierda a derecha*, no *a la vez*… qué significa esto en tu código? Pasito a pasito:

**`if (a == b == 3)`**

1. **Primero `a == b`:** Imaginemos que esto es verdadero, lo cual devolverá `true`, obteniendo la expresión siguiente: `if (true == 3)`
2. **Segundo paso, `true == 3`:** Aquí lo que tenemos es un error *incomparable types: boolean and int*, meec, resulta que ese `if` tan *fácil de entender* no era ni válido!

---

### Entonces no puede hacerse esto :(

Si, si puede hacerse:

```
int a = 4, b = 4;
if(a == b == true)
    System.out.println("Es correcto");
```

Esto es una expresión válida que imprimirá el mensaje "Es correcto"... pero obviamente comparar `true == true` no tiene mucho sentido así que aunque *técnicamente es posible* hacer lo que quieres, ***no se debe***, pues en el mejor de los casos no aporta absolutamente nada.

En el peor de los casos... bueno, dará error, y aunque no de error, en el momento que quieras añadir alguna condición diferente a la comprobación te empezarás a complicar sobremanera para que todo se ejecute correctamente.

---

Si todos usamos `a == b && b == 3` es por algo, y es mucho más *legible*!