# /SentenciaIF.java:35: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<='

Tags: java

Este es el programa y el error me sale en cuando quiero comparar la temperatura.

Dice que estoy comparando un boolean con un int y no se porqué sucede eso si en ningún momento he metido ningún booblean.
Gracias de antemano.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SentenciaIF {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

        String nombre;
        System.out.println("¿Podría ser tan amable de decirme su nombre?");
        nombre=teclado.nextLine();
  
        int edad;
        System.out.println ("Bonito nombre, ¿edad?");
        edad=teclado.nextInt();
  
        String ciudad;
        System.out.println("Qué mayor,¿en qué ciudad se encuentra usted?");
        ciudad=teclado.nextLine();
        ciudad=teclado.nextLine();
  
        int temperatura;
        System.out.println ("Buen sitio,¿a qué temperatura se encuentra?");
        temperatura=teclado.nextInt();
  
        int añodenacimiento = 2021-edad;

        System.out.println (nombre + " ha nacido en el año " + añodenacimiento + "." );
        if (temperatura <= 10){
            System.out.println("En " + ciudad  + " hace mucho frío");
        } else if (10 < temperatura <= 20){
            System.out.println("En " + ciudad  + " hay un tiempo nublado");
        } else if (20 < temperatura <= 30){
            System.out.println("En " + ciudad  + " va haciendo calorcillo");
        } else if (temperatura > 30){
            System.out.println("En " + ciudad  + " hace un clima tropical");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Temperatura no válida.");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que intentas comparar aquí: `} else if (10 < temperatura <= 20){`  y aquí: `} else if (20 < temperatura <= 30){`?

Comment: Me llamó la atención tu If encadenado y la forma directa de comparar los valores, también trato de aprender. Cogí tu código y lo probé, pero esa construcción me da error. Al final tuve que hacerlos de forma tradicional "((temperatura > 10) && (temperatura < 20))". Un saludo

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Comparar valor de 3 o más elementos a la vez en JAVA](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/426064/comparar-valor-de-3-o-m%c3%a1s-elementos-a-la-vez-en-java) Esta pregunta es exactamente la misma, y en mi respuesta está explicado el motivo de por qué esa comparación no es válida en lenguajes tipados como java. Un saludo.

Comment: "y no se porqué sucede eso si en ningún momento he metido ningún booblean" -> Mira por favor mi respuesta en la pregunta que puse en el anterior comentario, verás como efectivamente ***SI*** has puesto un boolean!